# How does Laravel handle migrations that happen "out of order"?

Tags: laravel, migration

So, let's say on the first of this month, I create branch A, with a migration file named `2020_04_01_113108_modify_request_logs_table.php`

But let's say I don't merge this branch into my Master branch yet, and then I start working on branch B 2 days later, with a migration file named `2020_04_03_113108_create_label_logs_table.php`

So on the 4th, I merge branch B into master and run `php artisan migrate`, and it runs the second migration.

And then on the 6th, I'm finally ready to merge branch A into master and run `php artisan migrate`. Is there anything that's going to go wrong with this migration? Does the migration system care that the dates of the files happened out of order? Will it ignore the A-branch file because it's already run a migration with a date later than that file?

Comment: if you have commit the `request_logs_table.php` in branch A, after merging branchB to master, master have no that migration file in branchA, so after you run migrate cmd, only create the `label_logs`, and the `2020_04_01_113108` is before `2020_04_03_113108`, so it not be migrated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Migration that haven't been executed yet, will be.

To check this before hand, you can run `php artisan migrate:status` to see which one are already executed ('Yes') and the ones that aren't ('No').

The output will look like this:

```
+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
| Ran? | Migration                                                         | Batch |
+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
| Yes  | 2019_12_12_184629_create_users_table                              | 1     |
| Yes  | 2020_03_27_153830_create_another_table                            | 1     |
| No   | 2020_04_01_090622_modify_user_table                               |       |
| Yes  | 2020_04_11_102846_update_level                                    | 1     |
| No   | 2020_04_22_094132_dummy_migration                                 |       |
+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Acutally, Laravel will resolve this out of the box. All previously ran migrations are stored in your databse, in table `migrations`. Upon running new migrations, Laravel will compare them against the migrations that have already been run for this application, by looking in that `migrations` table.

I did some research, and actually found the methods in framework that do the described logic above. You can check them [here.](https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/7.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations)